# How to take image from cv2 and put it in a JSON table for a webhook

Tags: json, opencv, discord

I am trying to work on a program that takes a picture of a person then sending that picture to a Discord webhook.

Here is what it looks like currently:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret, frame = cap.read()

url = "i am not putting the link so no one hacks it" 

#for all params, see https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook
data = {
    "content" : "Say cheese ",
    "username" : "BOT"
}

#leave this out if you dont want an embed
#for all params, see https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object
data["embeds"] = [
    {
        "description" : frame,
        "title" : "PIC"
    }
]

result = requests.post(url, json = data)

try:
    result.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
else:
    print("Payload delivered successfully, code {}.".format(result.status_code))
```

When I run it in python it does nothing, can anyone help me with this?

I tried looking online but nothing helped.